# Flourish Excel melting my hair grass and ludwigia

Tags: aquarium, community-aquarium, aquatic-plants, plants

Folks, I got a nano-tank setup of 6 gallon (around 23 liters), in which I got:

- Tall Grass (*Eleocharis Vivipara*)
- Ludwigia Mini
- Dwarf Hair Grass (*Eleocharis Acicularis*)

For the first 3 weeks I didn't introduce any CO<sub>2</sub> source. They were green and growing slowly. But when I started to pour Flourish Excel, after 2 weeks I noticed some decaying leaves and stems. Dwarf Hair Grass got brownish in colour, only few of the hairs were green. *Eleocharis Vivipara* got messed up due to dying strings. I use to pour 2.5ml everyday in the morning. My substrate is Contro Soil with no additives like root tabs.

Please someone suggest me some recovery option to save this current setup or please suggest me the plants for this setup. I gotta medium LED warm light with red, blue and cool white. It's bright enough to touch the bottom layer of the tank.

For low tech tank I found some plant's

1. *Staurogyne Repens*
2. Dwarf Sagittaria
3. Christmas Moss
4. Java Moss
5. Glosso

If you have any opinion on the above please educate me and also give your suggestions.

Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks.